# Thymeleaf JavaScript Parameters in Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm working on a Spring MVC application. I created a chart today using AMCharts via a JavaScript function. I have three Arrays that I generate in Java within the Controller. In Thymeleaf, I pass the parameters to the inline script using the following:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var dates = /*[[${dateArray}]]*/ "time";
    var market = /*[[${marketCapArray}]]*/ "market";
    var price = /*[[${pricesArray}]]*/ "price";

    /*]]>*/
    var chartData = generateChartData(dates, market, price);

    function generateChartData(dates, market, price) {
       function stuff here;
    }
<script>
```

Code works perfectly fine on any desktop browser I have tested it on but doesn't render in any mobile browsers. I'm assuming this is due to the mobile browsers being unable to parse those variables. I can't verify that though because I'm unable to view the source using a mobile browser. Does anyone have any work arounds or solutions to passing variables to JavaScript using Thymeleaf that's mobile friendly or any idea why this might not be working in a mobile environment? Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Thymeleaf parsing happens before the html is sent to the browser -- there is no way the browser (mobile or not) is affecting the way Thymeleaf variables are parsed.  You also can actually view the source in both mobile Chrome and Firefox by manually typing `view-source:www.domain.com/page-you-want-to-view` in the browser, if you want to verify.

Comment: @Metroids appreciate the response! Different browsers handle client-side code differently. It works in desktop browsers but not mobile. Therefore, mobile browsers have to be having issues parsing the variables passed to the inline script. Also, that’s what I thought regarding viewing the source. But after trying it today in Safari and Chrome on iOS, google just gives me search results, even when defining the protocol before the URL and safari gives me a message saying it can’t display the response. What mobile OS are you using t

Comment: I am using Android.  Regardless, what I'm saying is that the Thymeleaf part happens before the browser is ever involved.  Thymeleaf parses and sends back the same HTML (without regards to whether or not the browser is mobile), so you'll (probably?) have to look somewhere other than Thymeleaf for the problem.  Have you tried using the Chrome dev tools to mimic mobile devices?